# How to align every n element in a ListView or ItemsControl in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Lets say i have Model

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in my ViewModle i have this list:

```
ObservableCollection<Person> People;
```

Normally the binding syntax looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What i want to achive is to have for each row 3 people.
So let's say People = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G}
I want to display it like:  
A B C 
D E F 
G

What is the proper way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could Use a **UniformGrid** as ItemsPanel like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```