# WPF - MVVM - Binding/Displaying <ObjectType>.Property to multiple columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

Update: [Basically Identical Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462728/how-to-align-every-n-element-in-a-listview-or-itemscontrol-in-xaml)

I have an `ObservableCollection` of type `<Item>`. An `<Item>` object has the `properties` Id, Name, and Description.

In WPF, I have a `UserControl` I want to `databind` the `ObservableCollection<Item>` to and display ONLY the Name. This is easy, right? I agree. However, I want to display the Names across three columns.

Below I am showing a basic difference (drawn up in Excel) between the typical behavior versus the desired behavior. It's showing a list of five Items, in the assumed order they appear in the `ObservableCollection`.

[image: Desired behavior versus the normal behavior]

In the past, my solution was to split the `ObservableCollection` into three separate `ObservableCollections`. I then `databound` each separately into their own `ItemsControl`, but I am pretty sure the process is affecting performance (among other things)...

So S.O., how do I do this properly? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related: [WPF MVVM Table Layout from Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546739/wpf-mvvm-table-layout-from-data-binding)

Comment: THANK YOU! I stumbled across a similar page a few weeks ago, but at that time I was looking for a different issue. I can provide a solution based off of the solution from the related link soon unless someone else beats me to it!

Answer (score 1):

@Ron Beyer provided a related question link, in the question's comment section above. While the question itself is for a different purpose, the answer to it helps answer my own question.

Basically, the answer is to use `<UniformGrid Columns="###">` inside the `ItemsPanelTemplate`. I was previously using `<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" />`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Or... if we bind the number of columns too...:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding ColumnAmount}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Thanks again [Ron Beyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4798077/ron-beyer) and by association his answerer, [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8)!

Comment: There is no need for yet another answer.